# Ansible. Установка расширений Firefox для всех пользователей Linux

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, ansible, firefox-extension

Столкнулся с проблемой. Хочу задеплоить расширение OneLogin на машины с помощью Ansible.

Есть инструкция по деплою расширений от Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Alternative_distribution_options/Sideloading_add-ons) по которой достаточно подбросить файлы расширений в правильном виде в нужные каталоги. Но, похоже, этого не достаточно - ничего не происходит. Так же читал что нужно создать настройку для разрешения установки расширений без ведома пользователя, но не смог понять в какой каталог и каким форматом размещать этот конфиг.

Может кто-то сталкивался? Или разрабатывает расширения для Firefox? Подскажите, как правильно оформить конфиг браузера?

Исходные данные:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 и 17.10
Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit)

id расширения взятый прямо из файла расширения: "extension@onelogin.com"
```

Каталоги куда кладу расширение:

```
/usr/lib/Mozilla/extensions/
/usr/lib64/Mozilla/extensions/
/usr/share/Mozilla/extensions/
```

Расширение пробовал размещать как в подкаталогах:

```
/usr/lib/Mozilla/extensions/extension@onelogin.com/{extension@onelogin.com}
/usr/lib64/Mozilla/extensions/extension@onelogin.com/{extension@onelogin.com}
/usr/share/Mozilla/extensions/extension@onelogin.com/{extension@onelogin.com}
```

так и в таком виде:

```
/usr/lib/Mozilla/extensions/{extension@onelogin.com}/{extension@onelogin.com}
/usr/lib64/Mozilla/extensions/{extension@onelogin.com}/{extension@onelogin.com}
/usr/share/Mozilla/extensions/{extension@onelogin.com}/{extension@onelogin.com}
```